# Could you clarify when to use "Though" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Ok, English textbooks mostly teach the structure "**Although / though**",

for example,

> - Although my wife and I are so busy,we spend time together every weekend.
> - Anne was fond of Tim, though he often annoyed her.

However, in reality, I heard a lot of people use "though" at the end of a sentence.

So, I checked the dictionary & found that "**Although**" & "**Though**" in the above examples are conjunction.

But, from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/though_2), "**Though**" is used especially at the end of a sentence to add a fact or an opinion that makes the previous statement less strong or less important

Example:

> Our team lost. It was a good game though.

But, for me, It seems that "**Though**" that is used at the end of a sentence is more popular than "**Though**" that is used at the start of a sentence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, we must remember that **"though" can be used as a conjunction and adverb,** whereas **"although" is a conjunction; it's never an adverb.** So "although" and "though" are only interchangeable when they are used as a conjunction.

As a conjunction, "though" is much more common than "although" in speaking.

When used as a conjunction, "though" or "although" can be used at the start of a subordinating clause whether this clause comes before or after a main clause.

As for the "though" as an adverb meaning **however**, you usually use it at the end of a sentence.

In the sentence "It was a good game though" presented by the OP, the "though" has been used as an adverb.