# Why is "though" placed behind the sentence

Tags: word-usage

Why is ***though*** placed behind the sentence

> I wouldn't say so, though.

. ( I constructed this sentence by myself)

Because I thought ***though***  more or less get the same meaning with ***although***? Or it's ok to place it also in front of the sentence?

Ex :

> Though I wouldn't say so.

Perhaps I just get influenced with my languange rule that we can't put "***though***" at the end of the sentence (assuming ***though*** gets the sense of ***although*** or ***even though***) so I feel a bit cumbersome mention it at the end of the sentence.

What is the difference between both sentences?

Comment: This link probably answers your question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/could-you-clarify-when-to-use-though-at-the-end-of-a-sentence?rq=1

Comment: "though" could be paraphrased *contrary to what you might expect, based on what I said just a second ago*.  It can be placed before or after the statement that seems to contradict the previous statement.  "It is a good restaurant. I would not go there, [though]." or "It is a good restaurant, [though] I would not to there."

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right. You can use 'though' both at the beginning and the end of the sentence with the same meaning as 'although'.

The only point is that they use 'though' at the end of a sentence in spoken language i.e. it's informal.

About 'even though', again the same meaning as 'although' but you put more emphasis on the contrast that exist between the two ideas when you use 'even though'.

To sum up, just 'though' can be used at the end of a sentence (or clause), not 'although' or 'even though'. Using 'though' at the end is very common in spoken language. And 'even though' highlights the contrast even more.

Comment: The *reason* is that 'though' is an adverb that can also be used as a conjunction (actually a contraction of 'although'), while 'although' is always a conjunction only.